# Disabling macOS focus ring in SwiftUI

Tags: macos, cocoa, swiftui

Is it possible to disable the focus ring around a `TextField` in swiftUI for Mac?

Answer (score 7):

I had that question as well, and after a couple hours of fiddling around, it seems like the answer is no. However, it is possible to wrap an NSTextField and get rid of the focus ring.

The following code has been tested in the latest release.

```
struct CustomTextField: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String

    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        _text = text
    }

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSTextField {
        let textField = NSTextField(string: text)
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.isBordered = false
        textField.backgroundColor = nil
        textField.focusRingType = .none
        return textField
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSTextField, context: Context) {
        nsView.stringValue = text
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator { self.text = $0 }
    }

    final class Coordinator: NSObject, NSTextFieldDelegate {
        var setter: (String) -> Void

        init(_ setter: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
            self.setter = setter
        }

        func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
            if let textField = obj.object as? NSTextField {
                setter(textField.stringValue)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

As stated in an answer by [Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi) to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60286113/2272431), it's not possible (before iOS 17 / macOS 14) to turn off the focus ring for a specific field using SwiftUI; however, **the following workaround will disable the focus ring for all `NSTextField` instances in the app**:

```
extension NSTextField {
    open override var focusRingType: NSFocusRingType {
        get { .none }
        set { }
    }
}
```

Not ideal, but it does provide one option that doesn't require stepping too far outside of SwiftUI.

Answer (score 2):

As identified by [George Valkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1692274/george-valkov) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813943/swiftui-remove-focus-ring-highlight-border-from-macos-textfield), as of iOS 17 / macOS 14, you can apply `.focusEffectDisabled` to specific sub-views or an entire view.

```
TextField("Search", text: self.$searchText)
.focusEffectDisabled()
```

Comment: Beware, it also needs:
.textFieldStyle(.plain)