# SwiftUI: Remove 'Focus Ring' Highlight Border from macOS TextField

Tags: macos, focus, swiftui, nstextfield

I used the below code to create a custom search bar in SwiftUI. It works great on iOS / Catalyst:

[image: SearchTextView on iOS / Catalyst]

...but when running natively on macOS, the 'focus ring' highlighted border styling (when the user selects the text field) rather ruins the effect:

[image: SearchTextView on Native macOS]

Using `.textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())` has removed most of the default styling from the underlying field (which I believe is an `NSTextField`), but *not* the focus ring.

Is there a way to remove this too? I tried creating a custom `TextFieldStyle` and applying that, but couldn't find any modifier to style that border.

```
public struct SearchTextView: View {
    
    @Binding var searchText: String

    #if !os(macOS)
    private let backgroundColor = Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground)
    #else
    private let backgroundColor = Color(NSColor.controlBackgroundColor)
    #endif
    
    public var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            
            Spacer()
            
            #if !os(macOS)
            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
            #else
            Image("icons.general.magnifyingGlass")
            #endif
            
            TextField("Search", text: self.$searchText)
                .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                .padding(8)
        
            Spacer()
        }
        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        .background(backgroundColor)
        .cornerRadius(12)
        .padding()
    }
    
    public init(searchText: Binding<String>) {
        self._searchText = searchText
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of iOS 17 / macOS 14, you can use `.focusEffectDisabled`.
You can also apply it to buttons or the entire view.

```
TextField("Search", text: self.$searchText)
.focusEffectDisabled()
```

Answer (score 22):

As stated in an answer by [Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi) to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60286113/2272431), it's not (before iOS 17 / macOS 14) possible to turn off the focus ring for a specific field using SwiftUI; however, **the following workaround will disable the focus ring for all `NSTextField` instances in the app**:

```
extension NSTextField {
    open override var focusRingType: NSFocusRingType {
        get { .none }
        set { }
    }
}
```

If you want to replace this with your own custom focus ring within the view, the `onEditingChanged` parameter can help you achieve this (see below example); however, it's unfortunately called on macOS when the user types the first letter, not when they first click on the field (which isn't ideal).

In theory, you could use the `onFocusChange` closure in the `focusable` modifier instead, but that doesn't appear to get called for these macOS text fields currently (as of macOS 10.15.3).

```
public struct SearchTextView: View {

    @Binding var searchText: String

    @State private var hasFocus = false

    #if !os(macOS)
    private var backgroundColor = Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground)
    #else
    private var backgroundColor = Color(NSColor.controlBackgroundColor)
    #endif

    public var body: some View {

        HStack {

            Spacer()

            #if !os(macOS)
            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
            #else
            Image("icons.general.magnifyingGlass")
            #endif

            TextField("Search", text: self.$searchText, onEditingChanged: { currentlyEditing in
                self.hasFocus = currentlyEditing // If the editing state has changed to be currently edited, update the view's state
            })
                .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                .padding(8)

            Spacer()
        }
        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        .background(backgroundColor)
        .cornerRadius(12)
        .border(self.hasFocus ? Color.accentColor : Color.clear, width: self.hasFocus ? 3 : 0)
        .padding()
    }

    public init(searchText: Binding<String>) {
        self._searchText = searchText
    }
}
```

Comment: A workaround is using .onTapGesture to update the same onEditingChanged Bool.