# How to remove the colored border around the DatePicker in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

[image]

The border shows when the date picker is selected. This is a MacOS app written with SwiftUI. Here is the code:

```
 DatePicker(
            "",
            selection: $viewModel.currentTimelineDate,
            displayedComponents: [.date]
        )
        .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813943/swiftui-remove-focus-ring-highlight-border-from-macos-textfield) by [**@TheNeil**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2272431/theneil), adding this should remove the focus ring for any `DatePicker` in your app:

```
extension NSDatePicker {
    open override var focusRingType: NSFocusRingType {
        get {
            .none
        }
        set {}
    }
}
```