# SwiftUI customized text field in OSX

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am creating a edit view in SwiftUI for Mac OSX. A user can change his profile. At the moment I am using default `Text()` elements to view his current values/settings.

Now I want to create a edit mode. I already created a button, which toggles the edit mode. If the edit mode is activated, I replaced every Text with a TextField.

When I took a look at Apple's contact book for Mac OSX, I found out that they are using a different kind of Text Field (see image)

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to use this kind of element in SwiftUI and in OSX? What are they called or are they just customized TextFields with Border? I couldn't find any official documentation about them. If somebody finds it, I would be very happy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, in general all you need is `PlainTextFieldStyle`, but as currently SwiftUI does not allow to turn off focus ring there is some workaround below to disable it globally for all text fields.

Anyway... I think worth posting, so here it is (tested with Xcode 11.3)

[image]

```
extension NSTextField { // << workaround !!!
    open override var focusRingType: NSFocusRingType {
        get { .none }
        set { }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Mobil")
            TextField("", text: $text)
                .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                .padding(1)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2).stroke(Color.white))
                .frame(width: 100)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.black)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped. What about that resize? In Apple contact book, it only has the width of the Text. Is that edit mode available in Swift?