# SwiftUI TextField cursor with wrong size and position in MacOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

I am using a TextField in SwiftUI for a MacOS application. I am trying to change the font size of my TextField like this...

```
TextField("Name", text: $s_name)
    .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
    .padding(5)
    .font(.largeTitle)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
```

The increased font size does work, however the cursor of my TextField is completed off. I have disabled the focus ring of the TextField aswell, as stated in the answer of Asperi [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60284197/swiftui-customized-text-field-in-osx)
However the bug appears even without using this fix.

The problem appears when I press in the TextField for the first time. The cursor it totally off place and at the wrong size. If I start to type, it gets corrected.

[image]

[image]

**Edit:** Have reported this bug to Apple in their Feedback app.

Comment: I had this problem too

Comment: @Asadefa I couldn't find any solution. I thought changing the TextField Frame Height, but nothing worked. If I start typing I got the correct height of the cursor. But If the String is empty, it gets back to small cursor

Comment: This is SwiftUI bug. Submit feedback to Apple.

Comment: @Asperi Will do, is there any workaround with Representable? I tried using NSTextfiele but wasn’t able to change the font size.

Comment: @Asperi I can't believe it hasn't been fixed yet apparently.

Comment: Can confirm the same problem with Xcode 11.5. Also, for `SecureField` the dots appears in the wrong size.

Comment: I have talked to an Apple engineer during WWDC and they confirmed it's a bug.