# difference between background color for TextField in SwiftUI between macOS and iOS?

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, textfield

I run into an issue I have no idea how to solve. I plan to have a shared code base for macOS and iOS with SwiftUI (as much as possible).

But already with something simple like setting background color for a text field there is a difference

Following code snippet:

```
struct NewTextField : View
{
   @State var d:String = ""
   
   var body: some View
   {
      HStack(content:
      {
         TextField("Date: ", text:$d)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .background(Color.green)
         /// ... more views
      }
   } 
}
```

This is simplified; I have multiple textfields on the real application with background colors depending on the content.

on iOS it looks ok; the full textfield background is set to the desired color; on macOS the TextField appear with white background and colored border.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Hmm, I looked further and just run over this additional line  
    .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())  

added it   

    TextField("Date: ", text:$d)  
    .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())  
    .foregroundColor(.black)  
    .background(Color.green)  

and it actually does create the desired effect; just don't understand why on iOS it is not needed; but on macOS ...

Comment: the hint came from here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60284197/swiftui-customized-text-field-in-osx

Comment: What's this?  .foregroundColor(.black)  You mean, .foregroundColor(Color.black) ?

Comment: @ElTomato Yes `.black` means `Color.black`. Both syntaxes work.

Comment: @AlanS Oh, okay.  Thanks.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

just to leave it not unanswered:

added

```
.textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
```

and it create the desired effect

```
TextField("Date: ", text:$d)
.textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle()) 
.foregroundColor(.black) 
.background(Color.green)
```

based on this post: [SwiftUI customized text field in OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60284197/swiftui-customized-text-field-in-osx)