# macOS-provided control to enter simple text

Tags: macos, swiftui

Is there a built-in way in macOS to ask a user to enter a string in a UI/window?

Similar to this default text input UI for Chrome:

[image]

Or, do I need to create my own?

Comment: see if that helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60284197/swiftui-customized-text-field-in-osx

Answer (score 1):

That is an alert. In macOS, you can add a `TextField` to get the value:

```
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    @State private var input = ""

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Alert") {
            showingAlert = true
        }
        .alert("The page at blah blah blah...", isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            TextField("What's your sign?", text: $input)
            Button("OK") {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do I think they want to initiate such a dialog from javascript though?... weird.

Comment: @jett8998: I'm not initiating it from JS. It's just a screenshot of a UI I was looking for.

Comment: @jett8998: The question is tagged "swiftui".

Comment: ye ik just I think iat's mistagged so I asked. Hunter's answer is perfect if that's what @c00000fd is looking for.

Comment: @HunterLion: Thanks. I probably don't know SwiftUI that well. But what if I don't have a push button and instead I'm activating this from the main menu?

Comment: You should get acquainted with SwiftUI: the `.alert` is a modifier that can be applied to any view. If you don't have a button, the menu item needs to change the variable `showingAlert`.